# Check Database ConnectionState

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm connecting to `Firebird Database` using C#
I can't find where to check the `ConnectionState` to the database
If I make new `fbConnection` inside project it's easy to check it by `fbConnection.ConnectionState`
but I have made this connection with wizard and it's saved in App.config file
I tried to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` but it doesn't have `ConnectionState`

So how can I check connection state that defined in App.config file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't understand how this thing (the connection) works or what it is. The [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class just helps you to retrieve the connectionstring (note the word string. It is just a string nothing more).

With this string you can build your real instance of an FBConnection and try to open that connection. Now you could check the ConnectionState.

So

```
 string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
 using(FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(connectionString))
 {
     // At this point the myConnection instance is certainly closed so
     // it is total useless to check the ConnectionState
     myConnection.Open();

     // At this point the myConnection instance is certainly opened,
     // otherwise you get an exception and your code cannot contine, 
     // so also here it is useless to check the ConnectionState 
     // however...
     if(myConnection.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Open)
     {
         .... do your stuff with the connection.....
     }

 }
```

For this code to work you need to have in your App.Config the appropriate section where you store the details required to connect to your database under the symbolic name "MyConnection"

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
        Database=YourDatabaseFile.fdb;
        User=YourUserName;
        Password=????whatever???;
        Pooling=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So I really have never needed to check the connection state of a connection. The only possible use if this property is when you want to keep a global connection instance and in various part of your code you need to check the ConnectionState before trying to open or close this global instance. This scenario is not the best way to work with a disposable object like the connection that should be opened for the shortest period of time possible and the immediately destroyed (disposed) And exiting from the using block disposes the connection.

Comment: I made connection with Data Source Configuration Wizard so I can use it at DesignTime
and when application start I change ConnectionString to what ever I want
It works perfectly without any problem and without need to make a new fbConnection inside my project I use connection in App.config anc change it when i want but can't check the ConnectionState

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, it may be useful for you.

https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/NETProvider/ci/0475d606c597498a99be50393646c1c92d773dd4/tree/examples/ASP.NET/web.config

Comment: This is about Configuration File, what I need is check the connection state defined in this file, Thank you